# Simple statistics - Average and global average

Tags: statistics

> There are two groups of English: intermediate and advanced.
>
> - The average girls in the intermediate group is higher than that of the boys in the same group;
> - The average girls in the advanced group is higher than that of the boys in the same group.
>
> It can be concluded that the overall average for girls is higher than
>   overall average for boys.

I would say we **can** conclude that the overall average for girls is higher. It can be verified by taking some simple numbers.

However, I feel like my teacher would not have given me this if it was that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true! This is a case of Simpson's Paradox!

[Wikipedia: Simpson's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)

For example, suppose we had 1 girl in the advanced group and 9 in the intermediate group. Meanwhile, we have 9 boys in the advanced group and one in the intermediate group.

Suppose the girl in the advanced group has a 100% score, while the average of the boys in the advanced group have a 90% score. And suppose the girls in the intermediate group have an average of a 10% score, while the boy in the intermediate group has a 0% score. Then the average of the girls is
$$\frac{1}{10} 100 + \frac{9}{10} 10 = 19,$$
while the average of the boys is
$$\frac{9}{10} 90 + \frac{1}{10} 0 = 81.$$

Comment: I knew there was a catch! Thank for the answer!